# MOV in series with the VCC-IO pin of FT232R

Tags: ftdi

[image]

Could someone explain to me why there is a MOV in series with the Vcc IO? Is it to cut power if the pin falls below a desired voltage?

(Here's [the application note](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/USB-to-RS485-Breakout-v11.pdf) for the circuit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to F1, it's not an MOV (though the symbol does look like it). In USB designs, it's a ferrite bead used to filter the USB 5V line and also incidentally to have a fuse to protect the USB port from the circuit drawing too much current. Since 500mA is the max to be draw per the spec, so the fuse limits the current in case.

Unfortunately most USB ports don't have any real provisioning for limiting the current drawn. Although the USB standard requires the device to inform the host if it will need more than the standard 100mA, the reality is that many devices don't do so and just draw whatever they want(fans, lights and other little USB gizmos come to mind). So the port doesn't limit anything and runs the risk of shorting if the board you connect needs more than it can provide. Many ports can provide more than 500mA, and I've read that some apple computers provide more than 1A, but you should never count on it.

The FT232 does provide the amount of current it needs (you can change it with the EEPROM programmer), but F1 is there to ensure that the rest of the circuit doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks!
One question...what do you mean by "the USB standard requires the device to request more than the standard 100mA"...it looks like you are saying 100mA is a minimum...is it true?

Comment: Sorry, mistake in the wording. Up to 100mA, it's all legal in the spec. But above 100mA, the device is supposed to ask during enumeration for up to 5 times the standard load. More than that is not allowed in USB 2.0 (I believe 3.0 allows more).

Comment: Is this a regular fuse, or something like a polyswitch?
here you can see a picture of it:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9822?

Comment: It's a ferrite bead. Take a look at the datasheet. FTDI has design informatrion there.

Comment: So F1 is not a fuse, it's a ferrite bead to prevent EMI, right?

Comment: It's to prevent EMI but also it has a rating and I believe it will blow if the current is above the threshold (so it will in effect as as a fuse).

Comment: Ok..last question..could you provide me a real example like a datasheet or part number of a bead like this, so I might see more information?

Comment: Sure. FTDI offers  BK0603HS330-T  as an example:

http://www.yuden.co.jp/ut/product/category/emisuppression/BK0603HS330-T.pdf

I guess my posts made it seem as if this was for current limiting. In fact the EMI is more important(although current limiting is a desirable effect).

Comment: FYI, FTDI has design guidelines here:
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_146_USB_Hardware_Design_Guidelines_for_FTDI_ICs.pdf